# Laravel - sort array from other class by SQL table column

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling an array of all the comments of a poll by using the following code:

```
$poll = Poll::find($id);
      return view('pages.poll', ['poll' => $poll, 'comments' => $poll->comments]);
```

and the links between Comments and Polls are the following:

**Comment.php**

```
public function poll() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Poll::class, 'poll_id');
}
```

**Poll.php**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'poll_id');
}
```

Finally, I would like to sort the array `comments` coming from `$poll->comment` by the column `likes` in the Comment table, something like `DB::table('comment')->orderBy('likes')->get();`.

**Is there any way to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$poll->comments->sortBy('likes')
```

Comment: Link to the docs for sort by: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can do this.

1. Add `orderBy('likes')` directly to your `comments` relationship:

`Poll.php`:

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'poll_id')->orderBy('likes');
}
```

Now, any time you access `$poll->comments`, they will be automatically sorted by the `likes` column. This is useful if you *always* want `comments` in this order (and it can still be overridden using the approaches below)

2. "Eager Load" `comments` with the correct order:

In your Controller:

```
$poll = Poll::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
  return $query->orderBy('likes');
})->find($id);

return view('pages.poll', [
  'poll' => $poll,
  'comments' => $poll->comments
]);
```

`with(['comments' => function ($query) { ... }])` adjusts the subquery used to load `comments` and applies the ordering for this instance only. Note: Eager Loading for a single record generally isn't necessary, but can be useful as you don't need to define an extra variable, don't need to use `load`, etc.

3. Manually Load `comments` with the correct order:

In your Controller:

```
$poll = Poll::find($id);
$comments = $poll->comments()->orderBy('likes')->get();

return view('pages.poll', [
  'poll' => $poll,
  'comments' => $comments
]);
```

Similar to eager loading, but assigned to its own variable.

4. Use `sortBy('likes')`:

In your Controller:

```
$poll = Poll::find($id);

return view('pages.poll', [
  'poll' => $poll,
  'comments' => $poll->comments->sortBy('likes')
]);
```

Similar to the above approaches, but uses PHP's sorting instead of database-level sorting, which can be significantly less efficient depending on the number of rows.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortbydesc